# Eloquent model toArray() looses type for keys

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I use illuminate 5.1.* - (actually      "`laravel/lumen-framework": "5.1.*`")

My problem is that I have different behaviour when I do

```
var_dump($model->toArray());
```

for two different environment (but with similar `php version 5.6.8-1~dotdeb+wheezy.1 vs PHP 5.6.10-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1`) , and same vendor packages).

In the first environment, the integer attributes will be int:

```
array:4 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "value" => "email"
  "standard" => 1
  "order" => 0
]
```

in the second one, its string:

```
array:4 [▼
  "id" => "1"
  "value" => "email"
  "standard" => "1"
  "order" => "0"
]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: First you should check if the one that is casting badly is actually pulling the data from database correctly. It depends on what MySQL driver you are using. MySQLND is doing it right while libmysql is fetching all values as strings so maybe that's the case. So first try to dump model on this second environment before casting to array and check if its attributes are correct. I'd bet that they are not ;)

Comment: In the meanwhile, I find the solution that you are talking about. Installing, apt-get install php5-mysqlnd solved the problem. I think that this is interfining with toArray method, and they should put mysqlnd as a dependency or ar least as a suggest.

Comment: Actually this is not interfering with toArray() method as I already mentioned. The difference comes from the database connector that is either fetching all data as string(libmysql) or casting values to for example integers(mysqlnd). So this is purely server-side issue that you can not solve by using composer deps as it is about Linux package, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in what MySQL driver you are using. MySQLND is fetching **AND casting** values while libmysql is just fetching all values as strings. It has nothing to do with Laravel itself, neither with PHP. It is just the problem with database connector you are using for speaking with database. Simple 
`apt-get install php5-mysqlnd` should do the trick.